# Which permissions are required in Facebook API to go from 'notConnected' to 'connected'

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, status

http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed

In the above example from the Facebook test environment, status can take on one of three values:
1)connected
2)notConnected
3)unknown

These states, according to the API, correspond to the following descriptions:
1) Connected
2) Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
3) Not logged into Facebook at all.

How does a user go from being 'connected' to an application to not being 'connected'?  That is, what are the minimum permissions the user must grant the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user "connects" with your application, there is a basic set of permissions that are given to your application by default. Here is an image that depicts the permissions given by default to an App: [image]

You can, however, ask for extended permissions listed here: [Extended Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

Comment: Oh man, I can't thank you enough.  If I want a user to only connect with my app using the most basic permissions (ie. default permissions), how would I ask the user this?  Is there a specific permission that encompasses this option?

Comment: By default you get "basic information" which includes name, profile picture, gender, networks, user ID, list of friends, and any other information you've shared with everyone. That's just by not specifying any additional permissions.

Comment: Just by going through the connection process you get the basic privileges. No need to explicitly ask for any. Of course, you can ask for the "offline_access" extended permission if you wish to access the user data even when he/she is not logged in.